# Why is my counting wrong? Counting the number of distinct permutations such that no two adjacent letters are the same

Tags: combinatorics

There are three islands labelled $A$, $B$, and $C$. A grasshopper is on island $A$ and hops to one of the two other islands every minute. In how many different ways can the grasshopper end up at island $C$ after seven minutes?

Proposed solution: Consider the incomplete sequence $A$ _ _ _ _ _ _ $C$. We consider the equivalent problem of finding the total permutations possible of the above sequence when inserting the letters $A$, $B$, or $C$ into one of the slots such that the following is obeyed:

- Adjacent slots do not contain the same letter

In the first four slots, each slot has $2$ possibilities for a letter. Regarding the antepenultimate slot, there are two cases:

1. containing $A$ or $B$ implies the penultimate slot must contain $B$ or $A$ respectively. That is, the choice of letter is fixed.
2. containing $C$ implies the penultimate slot must contain $A$ or $B$. That is, there are $2$ choices of letter.

Adding the two cases and subtracting off what I think we are overcounting: $2^6 - 2^4$ is my answer. However, by explicit counting I arrive at $43$.

I want a combinatorial answer so why is my counting wrong?

Comment: Do you want an explanation of why you are wrong, or do you want a correct argument?

Comment: I would say: $2^6$ choices of letters for the first 6 slots, subtract those where you now end with CC, which is $2^5$, except that you subtracted those which end $CCC$, which were never there in the first place ..., so you end up with $2^6-2^5+2^4-2^3+2^2-2+1=43$ possibilities.

Comment: @mcd how can you end with $CC$?

Comment: One of those C's is the last one that is always there: e.g. one of the $2^6$ choices is A_B_A_B_A_B_C_C.

Comment: Can you explain where you thought the $- 2^4$ came from?

Comment: @mcd not sure I am following, A_B_A_B_A_B_C_C is not a valid sequence. or am I losing something?

Comment: But the counting method is to include some invalid choices to start with ($2^6$) and then subtract the ones that turn out to be invalid. I thought that was what you did in the first place. My argument might be clearer recursively: [number of choices with 7 letters including no pairs and starting with A and not ending in C] = $2^6$ - [number of choices with 6 letters including no pairs and starting with A and not ending in C].

Comment: @mcd I am not the OP:)

Comment: Sorry. I got confused with the handles. I've written a fuller answer below @l4telearner.

Comment: @mcd no problem. upvoted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notation: letter 1 is A, letter 8 is C. We need to choose six letters to fill slots 2 to 7. There are $2^6$ ways of doing this with no A in slot 2 and no adjacent letters identical in slots 2 to 7. The problem is that there might be a C in slot 7, so CC at the end. We don't want to count these, so need to subtract all the sequences we initially counted which have a C in slot 7. But this is same problem as before, with six rather than seven jumps. So if $N(7)$ is the answer you want, $N(7) = 2^6 - N(6)$, and repeating this argument gives $N(7) = 2^6 -2^5 + 2^4-2^3+2^2-2+1$.

Comment: Really astonishing! +1

Comment: Glad you like it @ajotatxe . What is nice is that you'd intuitively expect $\frac{2}{3}$ of the  $2^6$ to have A or B, rather than C, in slot 7 - and $2^n - 2^{n-1} + ...$ does indeed tend to $\frac{2}{3} 2^n$ as $n$ gets larger. The slight discrepancy is caused by the slightly higher chance that A will appear in odd-numbered slots, because A is in slot 1, so can't be in slot 2. If the first letter was B, the result would be the same, of course, but with first letter C you get only 42 of the 64 initial arrangements working, as C is slightly more likely to appear in slot 7.

Comment: I had not been considering the $CCC$ and such sequences! Agh, such a mistake. 

Wonderful explanation, thank you.